# Write as an algebraic expression in u

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The problem is:
$tan (csc^\left(-1\right)u)$

When I work this problem I get:
$1/\sqrt(u^2-1)$.
The text gets:

$\vert u\vert/u\sqrt(u^2-1)$

Rationalizing my denominator doesn't produce the text result.  What's up with this?

Comment: At some point in your work, you probably made the incorrect simplification $\sqrt{u^2} = u$.

Comment: No, I did not make that incorrect simplification.

Comment: $10\$$ says that you did, because the *exact term that you're missing* is the sign function of $u$. Post your work, and we can probably find exactly where it is.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$\csc^{-1}u=y$

using https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values, $-\dfrac\pi2\le y\le\dfrac\pi2,y\ne0$

$\csc y=u$

$\cos y=+\sqrt{1-\dfrac1{u^2}}=\dfrac{\sqrt{1-u^2}}{|u|}$

$\tan y=?$

Comment: would be exactly what I got, which was not the text answer.

Comment: @user163862 It really wouldn't, because the sine of $y$ is $1/u$, and the $u$ here and the $|u|$ in the cosine are what you're missing.